# How to implement Comparable in KotlinPoet?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

Submitted by [Fleshgrinder](https://github.com/Fleshgrinder) on [GitHub](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet).

How is it possible to implement `Comparable` for the class that is currently being generated?

There is the `ParameterizedTypeName.get(Comparable::class, ?)` method but it is unclear how the second parameter could be passed. The only thing available while generating a class is the `ClassName` of it.

Minimal example:

```
FileSpec.builder("com.fleshgrinder", "KotlinPoet").apply {
    val className = ClassName("com.fleshgrinder", "KotlinPoet")
    addType(TypeSpec.classBuilder(className).apply {
        addSuperinterface(ParameterizedTypeName.get(Comparable::class, Any::class))
    }.build())
}.build().writeTo(System.out)
```

Which generates:

```
package com.fleshgrinder

import kotlin.Any
import kotlin.Comparable

class KotlinPoet : Comparable<Any>
```

What I would like to have:

```
package com.fleshgrinder

class KotlinPoet : Comparable<KotlinPoet>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ClassName` has the following extension method:

```
fun ClassName.parameterizedBy(vararg typeArguments: TypeName)
```

Here's how you can apply it to your use case:

```
val className = ClassName("com.fleshgrinder", "KotlinPoet")
val comparable = Comparable::class.asClassName().parameterizedBy(className)
```

Please note that due to an [IDE bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15286) you'll need to manually add the following import:

```
import com.squareup.kotlinpoet.ParameterizedTypeName.Companion.parameterizedBy
```

Comment: Thanks @АлександрКундрюков, I've updated the answer!